# Futuristic arcade spaceship game where your ship gains wings and wheels, collecting power-ups—from the late 80s/early 90s

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

Can anyone identify this game from the late 80s to the early 90s?

What I remember about this game is that it had some very particular mechanics. For example, in some levels, your ship had wings, and you would fly across the screen (though I can’t recall whether it was a horizontal or vertical view). In the next level, your vehicle changed and had wheels, and you advanced through the level, having to jump at certain points.

Another mechanic of the game was that you collected power-ups (similar to the *Darius* games) and ended up with extra things to shoot on either side of the ship. The game’s look was futuristic and had nothing to do with a game like WWII or the like.

Comment: Side scrolling, vertically scrolling or both?